# Windsor Dependencies injection in mvc 4 rc into parametereized apicontroller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, dependencies, castle-windsor

So, i used [Mark Seemann's](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectionInASPNETWebAPIWithCastleWindsor.aspx) example to do dependency injection with Windsor in MVC 4 RC Web Api, but i get an exception saying that it can't resolve the dependencies to my ApiController

```
public class StatisticsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IClickMessageProducer _producer;

    public StatisticsController(ILogger logger, 
        IClickMessageProducer clickMsgProducer)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _producer = clickMsgProducer;
    }

    public string Get(string msg, string con) {...}
}
```

My Global.asax looks like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // different configs removed for brevity

        BootstrapContainer();
    }

    private static IWindsorContainer _container;

    private static void BootstrapContainer()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer()
            .Install(FromAssembly.This(), new ProducerInstaller())
            .Install(FromAssembly.This(), new WebWindsorInstaller());

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(
            typeof(IHttpControllerActivator),
            new WindsorHttpControllerActivator(_container));
    }
```

The Installers gives Windsor the references needed to `IClickMessageProducer`. I have it working with `IController` in a genuine MVC 4 project so i'm confident that part is working.

To specify, this is the error message i get, when trying to access a method in `StatisticsController` with a GET call to the API:

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
    Can't create component 'APIMVC.Controllers.StatisticsController'
    as it has dependencies to be satisfied. 
    'APIMVC.Controllers.StatisticsController' is waiting for the following 
    dependencies: - Service 'Castle.Core.Logging.ILogger' which was not registered.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>...</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

The call being something like this:
"http://localhost:60000/api/statistics?msg=apitest&con=apimvc"

If anyone has a working example or just a comment to the problem about my Windsor implementation i'll be happy to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This(), new ProducerInstaller()).Install(FromAssembly.This(), new WebWindsorInstaller());`

this was the part at fault. As you can see I call `Install(FromAssembly.This())` twice witch caused the `LoggerInstaller` to try  to add a `LoggingFacility`twice causing an error.

The new implementation would look like this:
`_container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This(), new ProducerInstaller(), new WebWindsorInstaller());`

Answer (score 0):

Your ILogger implementation isn't registered with Windsor. Remove the ILogger parameter from StatisticsController and try again. If it works, you're going to need to register an ILogger implementation.

Comment: Actually that's what the FromAssembly.This() in the new WindsorContainer().install() method is taking care of, given the correct installer class is implemented in the project, see my own answer for the solution.